# Will re-installing "gnome session fall back" fix that applet error?

Tags: 12.10, gnome

After login I often get the error `applet complete has quit unexpectedly`.

> Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit
>   3.5.0-24-generic
>   12 GB RAM
>   1 TB HDD

When the message appears on boot up it always provides the option to reload, once that happens all is well. Message occurs 1 -2 a week.

Comment: This issue occurs on both of my pc's ... any help

Comment: The issue also occurs in daily 13.04

Comment: Well I've not had this occur in April - so I'm guessing that the newer daily releases and the final fixed this. (Linux de 3.8.0-19-generic) I'd like to answer my own question, but I don't think empirical answers are all that helpful to others.